# DomSanitizer error "URL Segment: 'null'"

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

Recently in our Angular 2 app, we added a video component via `iframe` to pull in external embedded videos.  Additionally, we sanitize these resource URLs via a pipe which leveraged the `DomSanitizer`.  The problem was we frequently, but not consistently, received the below error and the embedded video would not load:

> URL Segment: 'null'

Sample sanitize pipe usage:

```
<iframe [src]="(videoObservable$ | async)?.resourceUrl | sanitizeResourceUrl"></iframe>
```

The pipe method itself:

```
transform(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

Logging the value of the `url` parameter shows that the pipe is initially called with a parameter value of null and then again immediately after with value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that the `DomSanitizer` does not deal with `null` values very well and so the below modification fixed the issue by checking for null and setting the input value to empty string prior to sanitation.

```
transform(url: string): SafeResourceUrl {
        if (!url) {
            url = '';
        }

        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
```